# Azure Key Vault - Access denied

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault, azure-resource-manager

I am creating an Azure Key Vault. I am using the below ARM JSON template. I have an App created in Azure AD and I am trying to give that app all permissions so that I can use this Apps credentials to connect to the Key Vault from a Key Vault client.

I am using TFS, and have created a "Azure Deployment:Create Or Update Resource Group" Release definition task to automate this.

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "vaults_qnvaultdev_name": {      
      "type": "string"
    },
    "vaults_location": {     
      "type": "string"
    },
    "vaults_skufamily": {      
      "type": "string"
    },
    "vaults_skuname": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "vaults_tenantid": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "vaults_objectid": {
      "type": "string"
    }
  },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
      {
        "comments": "Generalized from resource: '/subscriptions/subscription().subscriptionId/resourceGroups/resourceGroup().name/providers/Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/[parameters('vaults_qnvaultdev_name')]'.",
        "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults",
        "name": "[parameters('vaults_qnvaultdev_name')]",
        "apiVersion": "2015-06-01",
        "location": "[parameters('vaults_location')]",
        "tags": {},
        "scale": null,
        "properties": {
          "sku": {
            "family": "[parameters('vaults_skufamily')]",
            "name": "[parameters('vaults_skuname')]"
          },
          "tenantId": "[parameters('vaults_tenantid')]",
          "accessPolicies": [
            {
              "tenantId": "[parameters('vaults_tenantid')]",
              "objectId": "[parameters('vaults_objectid')]",
              "permissions": {
                "keys": [
                  "All",
                  "Get",
                  "List",
                  "Update",
                  "Create",
                  "Import",
                  "Delete",
                  "Recover",
                  "Backup",
                  "Restore"
                ],
                "secrets": [
                  "All",
                  "Get",
                  "List",
                  "Set",
                  "Delete",
                  "Recover",
                  "Backup",
                  "Restore"
                ]
              }
            }
          ],
          "enabledForDeployment": true
        },
        "dependsOn": []
      }
    ]
}
```

The template executes fine, and the Key Vault is getting created. I also can see in the vault's Access Policies the Principal is getting added with all the permissions. However, after creating the vault, when I use the Principal's client id and secret to connect from a client application, I get an "Access Denied" error.

I have noticed that if I go through the portal and manually add the App through the Key Vault's Access Policies, the Vault client is able to successfully authenticate. Am I missing something here?

**Update: Issue fixed**
I gave the app permissions manually to the vault's Access Policy and checked the Resources Portal. Then I see that the "Object Id" for this App generated in the Resources portal is different from what I see in Azure AD - in the portal for this app. Any ideas why these are different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.keyvault/vaults).

> objectId  string  Yes The object ID of a user, service principal or
>   security group in the Azure Active Directory tenant for the vault. The
>   object ID must be unique for the list of access policies.

You could find the object id on `Enterprise applications - All applications` not `App registrations`.

[image]

You also could get the object id with Power Shell.

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal
```

The root reason is that when you register an Azure AD application in the Azure portal, two objects are created in your Azure AD tenant: an application object, and a service principal object.

> **Application object**
>
> An Azure AD application is defined by its one and only application
>   object, which resides in the Azure AD tenant where the application was
>   registered, known as the application's "home" tenant. The Azure AD
>   Graph Application entity defines the schema for an application
>   object's properties.
>
> **Service principal object**
>
> The service principal object defines the policy and permissions for an
>   application's use in a specific tenant, providing the basis for a
>   security principal to represent the application at run-time. The Azure
>   AD Graph ServicePrincipal entity defines the schema for a service
>   principal object's properties.

More information about this please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-objects).

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this answer on [how to add Access Policies to MSI via ARM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59367800/azure-devops-arm-deployment-key-vault-and-managed-identities) if you are wanting to achieve all of this via ARM.

This process is a little easier then app registrations as the App itself will have a registered identity. You can read more on [Managed Service Identities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview)