# Service Principal get unauthorized when doing Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell, azure-keyvault

So this is a weird one. I have created a KeyVault. I have added the service principal to the access policy of that KV, giving it all the permissions.

I run my infrastructure release from VSTS. There is a step in it where it runs the cmdlet `Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret` to get a secret out of KV. This step has the service principal connection set up and it works.

I ran this yesterday, and it worked fine. I needed to run the infrastructure again, as I had made a change to the ARM template. But when it got to the `Get-AzureKeyVaultSecret` part, it failed and I got this error:

> Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault.Models.KeyVaultErrorException: Operation
>   returned an invalid status code 'Unauthorized'

This makes no sense. This exact same service principal has done this before. Nothing has changed. The app still is in the access policy of the KV. The connection from VSTS still works.

What is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Azure AD? You can get the application with something like this:

```
$application = Get-AzureRmADApplication | ? { $_.DisplayName -match "xxx" }
Get-AzureRmADServicePrincipal | ? { $_.DisplayName -match "xxx" }
Get-AzureRmADAppCredential -ApplicationId $application.ApplicationId
```

This should determine if the application is setup correctly and the principal's credentials aren't expired etc.

That that looks good, then you need to check the permissions on the key vault are assigned to the ObjectId of the principal (not the application).

If that's also right, then it might be a problem with the code not running under the credentials you think it is.  You could try turning on logging for the key vault (under Diagnostics Logs in the Azure Portal) which should give you some information as to what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

As Dainel said, you should check your user's object id is right. It is similar with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46334547/azure-key-vault-access-denied/46337276) on SO.

You could find the object id on `Enterprise applications - All applications` not `App registrations`.

[image]

You also could get the object id with Power Shell.

```
Get-AzureADServicePrincipal
```

Comment: Hi, does it work for you? Please let me know if you would like further assistance.